# put index and data to dict

Tags: python, numpy, nearest-neighbor, knn

```
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols)
vec= np.random.rand(1,cols)
d = ((data-vec)**2).sum(axis=1)  # compute distances
ndx = d.argsort()
```

than I can take first k

```
ndx[:k]
```

but if have

```
d1 = ((data1-vec)**2).sum(axis=1)  # compute distances
    ndx1 = d1.argsort()
d2 = ((data2-vec)**2).sum(axis=1)  # compute distances
    ndx2 = d2.argsort()
```

I need to concatenate values+indexes of ndx1+ndx2 and sort by value (take k nearest vectors from 2k vectors).

How can it be done? Do I need to use dict?

**UPDATE:**

I can't stack data1 and data2 because then it doesn't fit in RAM. I read my big array using numpy.memmap by chunks(1 chunk = data).

For example this works, but only for small sizes.So I need to process data iteratively by chunks.

```
import numpy as np
import time


rows = 10000
cols = 1000
batches = 5
k= 10
fp = np.memmap('C:/memmap_test', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(rows*batches,cols))

vec= np.random.rand(1,cols)

t0= time.time()
d = ((fp-vec)**2).sum(axis=1)  # compute distances
ndx = d.argsort()
print (time.time()-t0)

print ndx[:k]
```

This approach don't work:

> ValueError: object are not alighn

```
t0= time.time()
d = np.empty((rows*batches,))
for i in range(batches):
    d[i*rows:(i+1)*rows] = (np.einsum('ij,ij->i', fp[i*rows:(i+1)*rows], fp[i*rows:(i+1)*rows]) + np.dot(vec, vec) -
             2 * np.dot(fp[i*rows:(i+1)*rows], vec))
print (time.time()-t0)
```

this seems to work

```
t0= time.time()
d = np.empty((rows*batches,))
for i in range(batches):
    d[i*rows:(i+1)*rows] = ((fp[i*rows:(i+1)*rows]-vec)**2).sum(axis=1)
ndx = d.argsort()
print (time.time()-t0)
print ndx[:k]
```

Answer (score 3):

*Hoping to have understood the question properly.*

If `data1` and `data2` have at least one of the dimensions equal you can stack [vertically](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) or [horizontally](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack) `d1` and `d2` and then `argsort` the stacked array.

This way the ordering will be done on all the elements of the two arrays, but you don't know which one was the original array.

I don't think that dict is the way to go, if not because dict are not ordered.

### Edit: problem with memory.

An approach that come to my mind goes more or less like this:

```
#read the first batch and compute distances
# save the first k indeces and values
masterindex = d.argsort()[:k]
mastervalue = d[masterindex]

for i in (all the other batches):
    #read the following batch and compute distances
    tempindex = d.argsort()[:k]
    tempvalue = d[tempindex]
    # get the tempindex as absolute position with respect to the whole file
    tempindex += n_rows_already_read # by previous batches

    #stack the indeces and value arrays
    masterindex = np.concatenate([masterindex,tempindex])
    mastervalue = np.concatenate([mastervalue,tempvalue])
    # argsort the concatenated values, then save the new sorted 
    # values and indeces
    indx = mastervalue.argsort()[:k]
    masterindex = masterindex[indx]
    mastervalue = mastervalue[indx]
```

I haven't test the code, so could be buggy, but I hope that it's clear enough and that does what you want

Comment: I can't stack data1 and data2 because then it doesn't fit in RAM.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is our solution:**

```
import numpy as np

rows1,rows2,cols = 1000,600,7
data1 = np.random.rand(rows1,cols)
data2 = np.random.rand(rows2,cols)

data = np.vstack((data1,data2))     #stacking data

vec = np.random.rand(1,cols)
d = ((data-vec)**2).sum(axis=1)     #compute distances
ndx = d.argsort()

k = 30

sdx = ndx[:k]                       #selected k indices of nearest points

f = (sdx<rows1)                     #masking

idx1 = sdx[f]                       #indices from data1
idx2 = sdx[~f]-rows1                #indices from data2
```

Comment: I can't stack data1 and data2 because then it doesn't fit in RAM.

Answer (score 2):

If you have memory issues you could do something like:

```
data1 = np.random.rand(rows1, cols)
data2 = np.random.rand(rows2, cols)
vec = np.random.rand(cols)

d = np.empty((rows1 + rows2,))
d[:rows1] = (np.einsum('ij,ij->i', data1, data1) + np.dot(vec, vec) -
             2 * np.dot(data1, vec))
d[rows1:] = (np.einsum('ij,ij->i', data2, data2) + np.dot(vec, vec) -
             2 * np.dot(data2, vec))
```

You need to know the sizes of `data1` and `data2` beforehand, to allocate the `d` array, but you don't need to keep the vectors in memory simultaneously, you could delete `data1` once you fill the first part of `d`, before loading `data2`. The way I am calculating distance above, as `(a-b)**2 = a*a + b*b -2*a*b`, is morememory efficient than your approach, especially if `cols` is large.

You can now sort the array `d`, and map it to the rows of your two arrays e.g. as in @Developer's answer.

Comment: See my update. I have error ValueError: object are not align(I think due to multiplication.)And I try to avoid create big d also.